# Byte in Actionscript 3? (from C++ to AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

how do i convert this C++ code to AS3

```
void myFunc(BYTE type)
{
//send type to the network server..
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such type as BYTE in ActionScript 3 but you can use 'int' instead.
It will looks something like this:

```
var socket:flash.net.Socket;
//...
function myFunc( type:int ):void {
  socket.writeByte( type );
}
```

As it said in Socket docs: "The low 8 bits of the value are used; the high 24 bits are ignored." So only 8 bits will be written to socket just like it is expected with BYTE in C++.